# HTML Select Input Bug on iOS11

Tags: html, ios, cordova, knockout.js, ios11

HTML Select Input Dropdown is not getting dismissed properly on iOS 11. Upon closing the dropdown, an empty dropdown with blank options reappears in its place.

Nothing has changed, and we started getting complaints from iOS users, we could not replicate. Updated iOS to latest and now can replicate. The issue is, that they are always blank, from then on.

Pressure has been put on us to resolve this issue, has anyone came across this issue and have a workaround to resolve?

This is a cordova application, jQuery, bootstrap and knockoutjs. Any help be appreciated. I know it may be vague and no code but this is basic html selects.

[image: dropdown bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to ios 11.2 and issue has been resolved. After reading plenty of news articles this was nothing compared to the list of bugs that went out on this version.